# CSS 100% height layout

Tags: css, layout, height

I know this is a sort of a common problem, and I looked up some solutions, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I would like to convert [this](http://pastehtml.com/view/av6fb8bir.html) to a tableless layout.

[image]

Note: header and footer have to be set to a fixed height in pixels (50px is ok).

The main problem I'm having is that I cannot get that "big box" in the middle to behave like it does when it's done with tables. There are solutions which work OK for a variable length content (text, images), but I would like this box look and behave like a box - with borders, rounded corners and all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172918/div-100-height-works-on-firefox-but-not-in-ie-what-to-do

Comment: Here's an more example: http://www.reallinks.org/DIV-Header-Layout-100-Height/ + 2 Colummns / Left and Right

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do it with table style CSS properties, but still retain table less markup (which is still a win).

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><div>header</div></div>
    <div id="content"><div>content</div></div>
    <div id="footer"><div>footer</div></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;   
    text-align: center;
}

#container > div {   
    display: table-row;   
    width: 100%;
}

#container > div > div {   
    display: table-cell;   
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:10px; 

}

#header > div {
    height:50px; 
    border:solid 2px #aaa;
}

#content > div {
    height: 100%;    
    background:#f0f4f0; 
    border:solid 2px #5a5;
}

#footer > div {
    height:50px; 
    border:solid 2px #a55;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wGHte/).

Comment: Oh, yes, I think I can :) That's pretty great. Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: Table-styles are not very well supported in older browsers, if that matters to you.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter to me (I require WebSockets anyway), but if someone comes up with an alternative answer, that might help others. It might be even better and earn some love in the form of points.

Comment: @Beejamin Not supported in < IE8, unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex - that's true. Also, and it doesn't apply to your example specifically, but Webkit browsers also require you to have your `display:table-cell;` elements wrapped in a `display:table-row;` and `display:table;` element. I guess that makes sense, but it's not always convenient to rely on having two layers of wrappers! Good answer, mate - +1 from me.

Comment: Note that the content box doesn't have a fixed height in this solution. It will resize to accommodate a tall image in it, for example.

Comment: Is this really table-less layout?

Comment: @drinchev Well, they're styled like a table but the markup doesn't consist of tables. Call it what you want.

Comment: just a small addition: add `* {box-sizing: border-box}` to get rid of the 2px offset due to the border

Answer (score 29):

'Multiple absolute co-ordinates' is a nice way to achieve this. This is when you absolutely position a box, then give it both top and bottom co-ordinates. Without specifying a height, you get a box which wants to be 10px from the top, and 10px from the bottom edges of its parent.

[Here's an example](http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/absoluteCoordinates.html)

There is an IE6 specific style you'll need to add, if you care about that browser.

[Here's an article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/) on the technique (plus the IE6 fix) - it's a good one to know, even if you don't use it for this problem.

Comment: Well, actually I think this is even better - less markup and no specific table like remnants. I was too quick to promote the answer, so I'm very sorry but I think I have to change it to this. Didn't expect that there would be another solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly for the app (single screen chat application). Thank you.

Comment: Excellent solution, and so simple when you think about it!

Comment: Wow! This is actually a much simpler way to do this! Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said anything about heights of your sub elements, so I have had to make some presumptions. You could use percentages if you wanted.

```
<style>
html,body {margin:0;padding:0;
}
#mainContainer {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#header {
height:15%;
width:100%;
background-color:red;
}

#center {
height:75%;
width:100%;
background-color:blue;
}

#footer {
height:10%;
width:100%;
background-color:pink;
}
</style>

    <body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="center">Center</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>

</div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes, agreed - I edited the question. They really need to be fixed height (like 50px).

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway. Percentage heights require the parent container to have a specified height. When the parent does not have a specified height, then height:100% is treated as height:auto. http://jsfiddle.net/ajVSd/1/

Comment: @Layke can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106602/how-to-make-image-stretch-to-a-specific-paragraph ?