# Set equal height on 3 divs

Tags: html, css

i created 3 divs , i have to set equal height of all i tried with height:100% but its not working.all of these div have variation on them content but i need equal height of all.please help me!

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

.b1{height:190px;width:150px;background:#963;float:left}
.b2{height:150px;width:150px;background:#955;float:left}
.b3{height:180px;width:150px;background:#966;float:left}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: `height:150px;` or whatever height you want?

Comment: [working like a charm](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb4nU/) what's the problem?

Comment: I need to support on web kit also in IE and all if possible.

Comment: @morpheus yes it is 150px but i tried with 100% but its not working.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski yes its working but i need fluid height.

Comment: give same height for every div like height:100px;

Comment: @Yajuvendra so this should be your question "how to set 100% height" - solution http://jsfiddle.net/Cb4nU/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X4HcY/

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski yes its working here but not in my project.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yaju99/9Z79R/) here is the my problem.

Comment: @Yajuvendra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158975/css-100-height-layout

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski it is in table and very complicated do you have any other example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set all parent elements height to 100%, in your case it will be:

```
body,html { height: 100%; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cb4nU/3/

Answer (score 2):

put this code in your css. i think this will help you..

```
 .b2{
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: ; 
    height: 100px;
    width:100px; 
    border: 1px solid ;
}
 .b2 {
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: ; 
    height: 100px;
    width:100px; 
    border: 1px solid ;
    }
 .b3 {
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: ; 
    height: 100px;
    width:100px; 
    border: 1px solid ;
}
```

cheers...!

Answer (score 0):

Wraping all 3 in a div with the height you want them to stretch to also works
http://jsfiddle.net/Cb4nU/2/

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc massa, accumsan ut volutpat id, gravida porta turpis. Duis tincidunt feugiat est nec rhoncus.    </div>
<div class="b2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc massa,</div>
<div class="b3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>


.a{height:300px;}
.b1{height:100%;width:150px;background:#963;float:left}
.b2{height:100%;width:150px;background:#955;float:left}
.b3{height:100%;width:150px;background:#966;float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi below code snippet will do the needful,

**CSS:**

```
.parent { display:table; }
.b1{ border:1px solid red; display:table-cell; width:150px;background:#963;}
.b2{ border:1px solid green; display:table-cell; height:150px;width:150px;background:#955;}
.b3{ border:1px solid blue; display:table-cell; width:150px;background:#966;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
</div>
```

Changes :

1. Added **parent** container div
2. Removed **height** & **float:left** property from all div's in css
3. Added **display** property for all div's in css