# cannot get height 100% to work in polymer elements

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use this technique

[CSS 100% height layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158975/css-100-height-layout)

to fill page height 100%

Ultimately it fails because DOM has custom tags that won't honor height tag

Example:

**Works**

```
<div style="height:100%">
  ok here
  <div style="height:100%">
    <!-- WORKS: takes full browser height -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Broken**

```
<div style="height:100%">
  ok here
  <my-tag style="height:100%">
    <!-- BROKEN : takes minimal browser height -->
  </my-tag>
</div>
```

I tried using

```
<polymer-element name="my-tag" extends="div">
```

but then page silently doesn't render anything.

Comment: Fwiw, "doesn't render anything" is actually the infamous "0-height" problem. Your element is rendered, but as Eric explains below it has wrong display characteristics. You should be able to see in inspector that it has a computed height of 0px. This doesn't really have anything to do with web components, you can always make up tag names (e.g. `<squid>Ink!</squid>`) and those have always defaulted to `inline: block` (they are instances of `HTMLUnknownElement`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, custom elements are `display: inline`. This means `height:100%` won't work unless you make the element block level:

```
:host {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The other issue is your declaration. When you use `extends` to extend another element, this is called a [type extension custom element](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#usetypeextension). Instead of declaring `<my-tag>`, it needs to be declared using `is=""`:

```
<div is="my-tag"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/bohumisa/1/edit

Comment: The `<div is="my-tag">` version will utilize the normal UA stylesheet and become `display: block` without the `:host` rule.
But if you do not extend from `div` (omit `extends="div"`), then you can use `<my-tag></my-tag>` syntax and it will default to `display: inline`.

Comment: Using extends="div" and <div is="my-tag"> worked perfectly.  Thanks!  I was already using "block" level by using display types of "table", "table-row", and "table-cell" which is described in the link i originally posted