# Polymer Layout and template

Tags: templates, layout, polymer

I am learninng Polymer (and having fun).

Sometimes though i have working code, 
but when i try to extract that to an element, it stops working, or gives unexpected results.

Below is an eample where is try to make a 'tall column' element.
The code works when put direct in body, but not from template.

What am i missing?

---

Some Further reading brought up this:

[cannot get height 100% to work in polymer elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821684/cannot-get-height-100-to-work-in-polymer-elements)

so i changed style - and it works ...
(How is it that after you post yr question you find the answer in 5 mins, i really tried earlier ...)

```
<style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }        
      .p_col {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: white; 
        height: 100%; 
        width: 60px; 
      }







<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="apple-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <script src="/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/components/core-item/core-item.html">
  <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body fullbleed unresolved>


<section layout horizontal style="height: 100%">
<section center center-justified style="color: white; height: 100%; width: 60px; background-color: darkblue;">
Tall column - works
</section>
<p-col style="height: 100%">So does this (fixed one) ...</p-col>
<p-col>But this not?</p-col>
</section>

<polymer-element name="p-col"> 
    <template>
    <style>
      .p_col {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: white; 
        height: 100%; 
        width: 60px; 
      }
      /* THIS SOLVES IT */
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }        
      /* THIS SOLVES IT */
    </style>
    <section class="p_col" center center-justified>
      <content></content>
    </section>
  </template>
  <script> Polymer('p-col', { 
    ready: function() {
    }, 
    }); 
  </script>
</polymer-element>  

</body>
</html>
```