# I have a vertical scrollbar with overflow set to auto and height to 100%

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

We've a problem in a website with Microsoft Edge. Some vertical scrollbars are visible in the .ic3-report-content-container. Check website [here](http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Bank%20Liquidity)

The CSS is:

```
.ic3-report-content-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

How is it possible that, with a height of 100%, Edge is showing a vertical overflow?

The containers div - parent `.ic3-report-editor` - has the correct height. Somehow the height of this div is smaller (no borders, no padding, no margins...)

Removing the overflow or putting `overflow-x:auto;` and `overflow-y:hidden;` fixes the issue. Is this normal, or an Edge bug?

Comment: If the element has padding and/or margin set, they will add to the element's height, unless you use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Please include enough code in your question to reproduce the problem, rather than linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

The inner content of the `div.ic3-report-content-container` exceeds the boundaries of the box, so simply add:

```
.ic3-report-content-container {overflow: hidden;}
```

to get rid of the scroll.

Comment: That's a bit of a hack, the question is why ic3-report-content-container has not the same height as ic3-report-editor even though the height is set to 100%

Comment: Normally, you can't set the 100% height, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158975/css-100-height-layout

Comment: Not sure to follow up, it's working an Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE10.. it's just a problem we got with Edge