# Google Maps not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Map that won't show up. The Problem seems to be the same in FF & Chrome, but even more "bad" in IE (always latest version).

In FF & Chrome I have a problem with the `position: relative;` css element style. As soon as I switch to (with dev tools) `position: absolute(or: fixed);` everything displays fine in FF. In Chrome the map only shows the upper 30% (from top).

In IE the map doesn't even get loaded.

Here's the script stuff from the `<head>`. Content is only for testing and means nothing.
*Note: I only use this to get the map loaded. This will be exchanged later.*

```
<!-- Script inside <head> tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?
        file=api&amp;
        v=2&amp;
        key=<?php echo self::GOOGLE_API_KEY; ?>&amp;
        sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() 
    {
        var startpos = new google.maps.LatLng( 50.978056,11.029167 );
        var ops = { 
             zoom:      6
            ,center:    startpos
            ,mapTypeId: 
                 google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                ,tileSize: new google.maps.Size( 256, 256 )
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map_canvas"), ops );
        var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng( 50.7510776,12.4820724 );
        var contentString1 = '<div align="left" dir="ltr" class="infowin"><h3>test</h3>testen</div>';
        var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow( {
             content:   contentString1
            ,maxWidth:  5
        } );
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker( { 
             position:  pos1
            ,map:       map
            ,title: 'test' 
        } );
        google.maps.event.addListener(
             marker1
            ,'click'
            ,function() { 
                infowindow1.open( map, marker1 );
            }
        );
    }
    </script>
```

This is the *whole* mark up for the page.

```
<!-- html markup - There *really* isn't anything else -->
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</body>
```

I have spend a lot of time on google without finding anything. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`html, body` should be `height:100%;`.

But keep in mind, if your map holder element is a child of another element then that element should also have `height:100%;`

Otherwise, setting just the html and body won't do you any good.

An Example to explain my point:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      html, body { height:100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="google-map-holder" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, if you're doing something like the above. The `height:100%;` won't work here.

To make this work, you have to do the same thing with all of the parents that the `#google-map-holder` is a child of, in this case we would add `height:100%;` to `#wrapper` element.

IF, the `#google-map-holder` element was directly outside the `#wrapper` element and a child of the `body` directly then just doing `html, body` would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `height: 100%;` of #map_canvas.

Add this to your <head> and it should work (tested in Firefox 5 and Safari 5.1):

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

For Details why this is necessary have a look at the first answer of this question:

[Div 100% height works on Firefox but not in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172918/div-100-height-works-on-firefox-but-not-in-ie-what-to-do)

Comment: I took a look at my basic stylsheet and thought this is already in there, but: No, it wasn't. Thanks for the heads up! +1