# css - 100% height with pixel min-height

Tags: javascript, html, height, css

My goal is to create a container which occupies 100% of the window height and, within it, have an image which is also 100% of the window height. However, I'd also like to set a minimum height on the container so things don't get *too* small.
For example:

```
<html>
    <body style="height: 100%;">
        <div style="height: 100%; min-height: 500px;">
            <img src="cool.jpg" style="height: 100%"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
```

*(I swear my webpage is cooler than this)*

Ok, everything works great. Until we shrink the window such that `min-height` kicks in. At that point the `div` stops shrinking, as expected, but the `img` continues to shrink with the window.

Any thoughts?
A pure CSS implementation would be ideal but I'm open to JS if need be.

Comment: Give `min-height` also to `img`. or to just `body` tag.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to show the problem?

Comment: Good idea: http://jsfiddle.net/xDczp/

Comment: looks good to me. which browser you testing on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about giving the image the `min-height` instead of the container?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** http://jsfiddle.net/NpqCW/3/

> Using my answer on the below question as a reference if you need more
>   detail and example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10582476/339367

Basically, what you were missing was the height:100% on the root tag which is `<html>`.
All parents must have this set for it to work, you were doing it on all except the root element which is `<html>`.

### UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/jDk3s/

Added min-height:inherit on the image to make it work on chrome.
It could also have been fixed by **removing** the min-height on parent div of IMG (but not sure if you really really need that or not).. so you could chose one or the other way.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (in Chrome 25 anyway). The div with `min-width` stays at 500px still but everything else continues to shrink to 100% of the window height.

Comment: @SeanConnolly I see, i didn't check it on Chrome. But it should be working now.. please check again.

Comment: Added link to new fiddle, forgot to put it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

id just set the div background to the target img, then restrict the height on resize through jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#cont {
background: url(path/to/cool.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-etc-vend-pref-background-size: cover;

}
</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">

  <div id="cont" style="height: 100%; min-height: 500px;">
    <img id="bg" src="cool.jpg" style="height: 100%"/>
  </div>


<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
   var  win = $(window),
       cont = $('div.cont'),
        min = 500;

    if (win.height() <= min){
      cont.height(min);
    } else {
      cont.height(win.height());
    }

 });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Although i like @linus's answer best, and would personally go for that, this is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/xDczp/5/

```css
.container {height:100%; width:100%;}
.content {height: 100%;}
.content img {height:100%; min-height: 500px; width:100%;}
```

The image height shouldn't drop below 500px.