# CSS - Why is my background color not showing in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background

Here's a practice site I'm messing around with.  I didn't create the theme.. but can't figure out why the background color disappears in IE 8 (the only version I have to test with)?

I used Firebug to try and pinpoint and it looks to me like it's looking at `.box .cnt` and the color is already set for that.

Any ideas?

http://unique-home-decor.info

Comment: Are you linked to the correct address?  That looks like a "spam" page to me.

Comment: @Jeff It could be a structural mistake. You currently have 191 Errors and 7 warnings for this page: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2funique-home-decor.info%2f

Comment: Maybe it's a layout or design issue, but there's so many ads it looks like a spammy link-farm page to me too.

Comment: Listen to @JonathanSampson's comment.  You will never get IE to behave when the HTML is not valid.

Comment: @Sparky672 That's actually one of the reasons why I *like* Internet Explorer - it keeps us accountable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is there, however IE8 doesn't like the class `cnt` height at `100%`. Check out this post for more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/176454/1220302

Also, take a look here for more information on the height property: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property

Comment: Please don't just link to another post without a detailed explanation.   Fully explain your answer only using the link as reference to support it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say it any better then what's stated in the post by @timblue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant user @timeblue in the post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/176454/1220302

Comment: If needs be, copy and paste from the original answer. If the links ever change in future then this answer is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this may help someone as it solved my issue.

IE version 11 = No background colour on my heading
Chrome/Edge = Background colour on my heading

The issue was with how IE handles RGBa progressive enhancement.

My original CSS:

```
header {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255);/*,0.80);*/
}
```

I had originally decided to add opacity to the header and make it a different colour using RGBa, but later decided to remove it.  I didn't consider that RGBa would cause an issue until I tested different browsers and so had LONG forgotten to change this.  Changing to:

```
header {
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

or simply:

```
header {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Solved my problem.  Solution here: https://css-tricks.com/ie-background-rgb-bug/