# jQuery autosize issue in Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket

I am very new to jQuery and JS. Recently i have been assigned to a bug, in which textarea should resize on focus according to the text present into that textarea.
We have used `$('textarea').autosize();` function in a JS file.
This works properly on recent FF versions and latest IEs (9+), but it's not working on IE 7 and FF 3.5.3

I found [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/), but didn't workout.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest could be that on the `focus event of the textarea`, u could populate the current text of the textarea to another `span` which is hidden in the view and has the same text styles as the textarea.

Once this new span has the text, u can get its `width and height` and then assign these to the textarea. Since these are very primitive actions, they must work in IE7 and FF3

Comment: Hi Bhumi..thanks for your reply. I have solved this issue. autosize plugin doesn't works for FF < 4.0 and for IE, after a lot of googling, i found that never give width/height in px for IE. Replacing px by % in css has solved my issue for IE. :)

Comment: Ohk ..I nevr knew that values in px where are an issue ... :)

Comment: :) me too before looking into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172918/div-100-height-works-on-firefox-but-not-in-ie-what-to-do

and for FF 3.6.9 i used this new plugin: https://github.com/gurglet/jQuery-Textarea-Autoresize-Plugin