# empty div percentage height inside table cell on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I would like to create some kind of a vertical separator between cells of a table. I can't use cell border cause the height of this separator must be smaller than the cell's height.

So I have add a new cell with a empty div of proper height.

```
<div> <--- width/height auto
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>content 1-1</td>
       <td rowspan="2"><div class="separator"/></td>
       <td>content 1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>content 2-1</td>
       <td>content 2-2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css

```
table, td {
   height:100%;
}

.separator{
   height: 80%;
   border: 3px solid black; 
}
```

see here something more complete:  http://jsfiddle.net/cCNP8/11/

So as a non-surprise this work on all major browsers except IE.
The height of the div doesn't matter to him and a square of 6x6px is displayed. It work if I set a height to the div surrounding the table but I don't want that, it must fit its content.

Any idea? I could totally do things differently.

Comment: try using this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/176454/1982680

Comment: I don't want to set any height to my container div. This height should be computed according to cell's content (other than the separator).

Comment: Found another way of doing it using absolute positioning but still not working with IE... IE is so full of fun. Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ykzfn/1/